# Managed Oracle access, support for "≤"

Tags: c#, .net, oracle, odp.net-managed

We have switched from unmanaged to managed Oracle in our Winform application and everything is working fine except for one detail. If I save the string `"≤"` to the database and then try to retrieve it again I get `"="` back. It is stored as an nvarchar in and I can see (via Toad) that it is in fact saved as `"≤"`. When we were running unmanaged data access we used `"NLS_LANG = SWEDISH_SWEDEN.WE8MSWIN1252"` but as far as I can tell this is not supported in the managed driver. The managed driver is supposed to use the .NET locale and the codepage in that is set to `1252`. Have anyone seen this and perhaps found a solution?

Answer (score 0):

You are right, ODP.NET Managed Driver is not `NLS_LANG` sensitive. It is only .NET locale sensitive.

However, TOAD does not use the ODP.NET Managed Driver thus you have to set `NLS_LANG` properly. If you set it to `.WE8MSWIN1252` then you must set in Options -> Files -> General -> Default Encoding to `ANSI`, resp. set ANSI in "Save" dialog.

Comment: Yes, I know. Toad shows the correct string, "≤", but our managed application does not.

Comment: Actually character `≤` is not supported by Windows CP1252, see [Windows-1252](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252#Code_page_layout). Maybe try to set .NET locale to Unicode (i.e. UTF-8)

Comment: Check this discussion: [Oracle Community](https://community.oracle.com/thread/2610675?start=15&tstart=0). Basically they say: It is not possible, use the unmanaged Driver. I assume your `NLS_NCHAR_CHARACTERSET` is `AL16UTF16` (as you use `NVARCHAR2`) data type which could be considered as "not common yet"

Comment: Hmm, I guess it's back to unmanaged then. Thank you for your help!